# uniroot() error in R - interval endpoints not successfully extended

Tags: r

I am new to the uniroot() function and repeatedly had problems with particular combinations of input values for my function that I would like to solve.

This is the error message I am receiving:

> Error in uniroot(fun, lower = 0.001, upper = 1e+08, extendInt =
>   "downX") :    did not succeed extending the interval endpoints for
>   f(lower) * f(upper) <= 0

And here is the code that I am running:

```
genTactFun = function(T1, T2, T3, T4, Tactive_exp = 0) {
  force(T1)
  force(T2)
  force(T3)
  force(T4)
  force(Tactive_exp)
  function(x) {
    0.25 * (1 - x ^ 1.2 / (x ^ 1.2 + 20    ^ 1.2)) * T1 +
      0.5  * (1 - x ^ 1.2 / (x ^ 1.2 + 150   ^ 1.2)) * T2 +
      0.75 * (1 - x ^ 1.2 / (x ^ 1.2 + 1500  ^ 1.2)) * T3 +
      1    * (1 - x ^ 1.2 / (x ^ 1.2 + 60000 ^ 1.2)) * T4 -
      Tactive_exp
  }
}

T1_obs = 1.131538625
T2_obs = 0.1921480684
T3_obs = 0.01067489269
T4_obs = 0.001186099188

fun = genTactFun(T1_obs, T2_obs, T3_obs, T4_obs, 0.3910554)
Res = uniroot(fun, lower = 1e-3, upper = 1e8, extendInt = "downX")$root
```

Can I still receive a solution to my problem using uniroot()? Or does this mean that the uniroot() function cannot compute a solution even when changing its settings?